# What functions are called before the Receive method of a input pin in directshow filters?

Tags: c++, directshow

I have built a filter graph successfuly, e.g. all connections between the filters could be made.
But when I run the graph it doesn't produces any output.
I used the SetLogFile method of the graph, but all it says is that there have been filters added and created, nothing else. The probelm seems to be that the Receive method of my inputpin is not called. Using debugging techniques I could determine that the following methods of my filter/pin have been called:

- Constructor of my filter
- Three times constructor of input pin (i have three instances of them)
- constructor or output pin
- Nondelegationqueryinterface
- 2 times GetMediaType
- 2 times pause of my filter (at the same second)

The code of my receive function does not get called.
I have also tried checking multiplReceive which was not called either.

Here is my source code:

```
#include "MyFilter\MyFilter.h"
#include <dshow.h>
IPin *GetPin(IBaseFilter *pFilter, PIN_DIRECTION PinDir)
{
    BOOL       bFound = FALSE;
    IEnumPins  *pEnum;
    IPin       *pPin;

    pFilter->EnumPins(&pEnum);
    while (pEnum->Next(1, &pPin, 0) == S_OK)
    {
        PIN_DIRECTION PinDirThis;
        pPin->QueryDirection(&PinDirThis);
        if (bFound = (PinDir == PinDirThis))
            break;
        pPin->Release();
    }
    pEnum->Release();
    return (bFound ? pPin : 0);
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_  HINSTANCE hInstance,  
    _In_  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_  int nCmdShow
    )
{
    //INIT GRAPH
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IGraphBuilder* graphBuilder = NULL;
    IMediaControl* mediaControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent* mediaEvent = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFilterGraph, (void **)&graphBuilder);

    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(L"D:\\TEMP\\debug1.log", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);

    graphBuilder->SetLogFile((DWORD_PTR)fileHandle);
    graphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&mediaControl);
    graphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&mediaEvent);

    IBaseFilter* source;

    hr = graphBuilder->AddSourceFilter(L"D:\\TEMP\\drop.avi", NULL, &source);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    IPin* sourceOUt = GetPin(source, PINDIR_OUTPUT);

    //END

    //SPLITTER
    IBaseFilter* splitter;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AviSplitter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&splitter);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }
    graphBuilder->AddFilter(splitter, L"Splitter");
    IPin* pinSplitIN = GetPin(splitter, PINDIR_INPUT);

    hr = graphBuilder->Connect(sourceOUt, pinSplitIN);
    IPin* piSplitOut = GetPin(splitter, PINDIR_OUTPUT);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }
    //END


    //LAV Video Decoer
    IBaseFilter* decoder;
    // {EE30215D-164F-4A92-A4EB-9D4C13390F9F}
    static const GUID CLSID_LAV = 
    { 0xee30215d, 0x164f, 0x4a92, { 0xa4, 0xeb, 0x9d, 0x4C, 0x13, 0x39, 0x0F, 0x9F } };

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_LAV, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&decoder);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = graphBuilder->AddFilter(decoder, L"Decoder");

    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;


    IPin* decoderIN = GetPin(decoder, PINDIR_INPUT);

    hr = graphBuilder->Connect(piSplitOut, decoderIN);
    IPin* decoderOUT = GetPin(decoder, PINDIR_OUTPUT);

    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    //myfilter

    IBaseFilter *myfilter;
    IMyFilter* myInterface;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MyFilter64, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&myfilter);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    myfilter->QueryInterface(IID_IMyFilter64, (void **)&myInterface);

    hr = graphBuilder->AddFilter(myfilter, L"MyFilter");
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }
    IPin* mypin0 = myInterface->GetMyPin(0);


    IPin* myoutpin = myInterface->GetMyPin(3);
    hr = graphBuilder->Connect(decoderOUT, mypin0);


    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    //AVI MUX

    IBaseFilter* mux;
    // {F7F627FB-45C3-4F6F-B99A-71C0BFE3B5B7}
    //{E2510970-F137-11CE-8B67-00AA00A3F1A6}
    const GUID CLSID_MUX =
    { 0xE2510970, 0xF137, 0x11CE, { 0x8b, 0x67, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0xA3, 0xF1, 0xA6 } };




    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MUX, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)& mux);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    IPin* muxIn = GetPin(mux, PINDIR_INPUT);
    IPin* muxOut = GetPin(mux, PINDIR_OUTPUT);
    graphBuilder->AddFilter(mux, L"MUX");

    hr = graphBuilder->Connect(myoutpin, muxIn);

    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;


    //FILEWRITER
    IBaseFilter* filewriter = NULL;
    IFileSinkFilter* fileSink = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileWriter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&filewriter);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = graphBuilder->AddFilter(filewriter, L"FIleWriter");
    IPin* fileIn = GetPin(filewriter, PINDIR_INPUT);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = graphBuilder->Connect(muxOut, fileIn);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = filewriter->QueryInterface(IID_IFileSinkFilter, (void **)&fileSink);

    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    fileSink->SetFileName(L"D:\\TEMP\\yc2.avi", NULL);

    /*myInterface->StartRecording()*/;
    hr = mediaControl->Run();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        long evCode;
        mediaEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);
        mediaControl->Stop();   
        //myInterface->StopRecording();
        CoUninitialize();
        myfilter->Release();

        return 1;

    } 
    CoUninitialize();
    myfilter->Release();


    return hr;
}
```

The problem is propably in my own filter. So what methods of a filter are called by the graphbuilder? If i know this i can implement this methods and place logging messages in.

Comment: To see the dataflow between the filters, you can use [GraphStudioNext](https://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/). Build the graph and then insert an "Analyzer-Filter" before and after your filter. In the property-page of the analyzer you can now see the input-samples and the output-samples of your filter. If there are just input-samples and no output-samples then you have a problem with your filter. If there is only one input-samples then you also have a problem with your filter! Because the connection works doesn't mean your filter works also!

Comment: Add logging to your own filter and first of all check whether your input pin object gets called Receive. This is where data arrives. Then follow your filter source code and ensure that this call to Receive on  input pin eventually results in output pin sending data down the stream.

Comment: i have added logging to my filter and i can now see that the input pin is created but Receive of it is not called. Do i have to implement certain functions in my pin or filter to get data flowing it through it. The connection between the pins could be established successfully, even the run method of the graphfilter returned S_OK.

Comment: could it something have to do with locks?